# Edit information in firebase, swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, email, firebase

How Can I Update the user Information in firebase! 
For Example, his email, password, and name, etc.

What firebase function would I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty vague question with numerous answers but here's the basics.

Assume you have a Firebase structure like this

```
users
  uid_0
    user_name: "Bill"
    email: "bill@yipee.com"
```

To change the user name from Bill to Leeeeroy:

```
var userNameRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/uid_0/user_name")
userNameRef.setValue("Leeeeroy")
```

The above is a small example. You should investigate using .updateChildValues as well.

The Firebase website has a really good guide on writing data, check it out!

[Saving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html)

If you are looking into modifying the actual Firebase user data, instead of a users node you have created, look into

> - (void)changeEmailForUser:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password toNewEmail:(NSString *)newEmail withCompletionBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( NSError *error ))block

here's the simple swift code to change the users Firebase email

```
myRootRef.changeEmailForUser("bob@thing.com", password: "old_password", toNewEmail: "new_password") { (<#NSError!#>) -> Void in
    print("done!")
}
```

Comment: I see! The second part of my answer, changeEmailForUser, addresses that. Firebase only stores 2 items: email and password and there are API calls for both of those. There's also a call to send a password reset email as well. All of the calls are listed in the API Reference on the firebase website. Try working with the changeEmailForUser call I referenced above and if you get stuck, open another question about that and post your code and sample Firebase structure (textual please)

Comment: It looks like I cannot ask questions until editing this one! :( http://screenshot.net/w9lm2f8 What shall I do to get back! I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Here's what you need to do; Based on the code you posted, you are trying to change a change value for the email key in the users node. My guess is that you want to update BOTH that node as well as the Firebase user login credentials. Please update your question to be more specific  and then post some code in your question of what you have tried. Posting your code (brief snippet please) and data structure (again, textual; Firebase dashboard and Export) makes it searchable and copy/paste-able into an answer. Please keep the code and structure brief. We can then take a look and provide direction.

Comment: Ok, much clearer question. But, now that we understand the scope of the question, the code you posted is pretty well off base. Firebase stores a username (email) and password which is used by Firebase internally to authenticate users. The /users node is one *you* create to hold additionally information about the user; they name, age, etc. So to update the /users node you created, use standard setValue calls. To update the internal Firebase parameters, use the call in your question. However, just make email, their email and password, their password.

Comment: I did use the call as you said. But, it did not work! Still gives me "there was an error processing the request"

Comment: As I mentioned, the code in your question is incorrect and will not work. You will need 4 separate calls. One to update the Firebase email, a Second to update the Firebase password, a Third to update the email in your /users folder and a Forth to update the password in your /users folder. I added the swift code to my answer to change a users Firebase login password.

Comment: The code you added is the same one as in my question. Still did not work.

Comment: You help me with how to change other user info like name, etc.