# Changing User Email and Password with Swift and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's my edit button for an iOS application with swift and firebase.

```
    var ref = Firebase(url:"https://·············.firebaseio.com")

    @IBAction func Done(sender: AnyObject) {

    ref.changeEmailForUser("users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/email",
        password: "users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/provider", toNewEmail: EmailTextField.text)
        { (ErrorType) -> Void in
        if ErrorType != nil {
            print("There was an error processing the request")
        } else {
           print("Email changed successfully")
        }
    }

    ref.changePasswordForUser("users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/email",
        fromOld: "users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/provider", toNew: PasswordTextField.text)
        { (ErrorType) -> Void in

        if ErrorType != nil {
          print("There was an error processing the request")
        } else {
            print("Password changed successfully")
        }

    }

ref.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(self.ref.authData.uid).updateChildValues(["name":self.NameTextField.text!,"about":self.TextView.text!,"Picker":self.PickerVar])




}
```

When the user clicks the done button I want to update all of his information in the firebase. 
Email, Password, Name, etc.

All of the information updated when I click the done button, except for email and password! 
It's says there was an error processing the request: 
[as the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV0Tz.png)

I don't know where 's the error! Did I use the changeEmailForUser and changePasswordForUser functions in a wrong way?

Here's the JSON tree:

```
  {
"users" : {
  "7b595e99-b20d-4961-bcf0-6c46956a0cbe" : {
      "Picker" : "Student",
      "about" : "Hey, I'm Here",
      "email" : "mariah@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Mariah Khayat",
      "provider" : "password"
    },
  "7eb23db6-6b56-4225-9306-22ed0b935b52" : {
      "Picker" : "Teacher",
      "about" : "Hi",
      "email" : "mmm@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Memo",
      "provider" : "password"
   }
  }
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit information in firebase, swift project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887692/edit-information-in-firebase-swift-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accarding to Firebase API making some confusion. after i seen the API https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_changeEmailForUserpasswordtoNewEmailwithCompletionBlock  There is clearly said:

[image]

So for the update Email For user this is not a part a update profile. So as per following you can change your email address:

```
 ref.changeEmailForUser("OldEmailthatYouuserForLogin", password: "correctpassword",
            toNewEmail: "newEmail", withCompletionBlock: { error in
                if error != nil {

                     print("There was an error processing the request")
                    // There was an error processing the request
                } else {

                    print("Email changed successfully")

                    // Email changed successfully
                }
        })

// Dont use edited email for the old email and edited password for the password make sure you are using your actually email and password
```

Comment: I tried to do what you did. Everything is updated, except for the email and password, it still gives  "there was an error processing the request"!

Comment: you need to store password as a individual filed. do not user provider set individual filed as a passwrod and set the password during register and use this field.

Comment: thre is E must be in small for email key. check your firebase databae and you are using Capital E in key of dictionary

Comment: Yes I noticed the E, changed it to e. But did not it work and still gives me "there was an error processing the request" as here: http://screenshot.net/nn4mrtd. I feel like the error is in the changeEmailForUser and changePasswordForUser functions, did I use the parameters correctly??? I do not know what's wrong!! :/

Comment: Here is the error description: http://screenshot.net/rrefdrr. What does that mean?

Comment: i think you are passing swrong uid. query is not finding user:(

Comment: print of the User id befor pass to update so you can get what happen else send me you project i can check it this is my email nitin@olbuz.com

Comment: check my update anaswer use actul password instead of using provider.

Comment: Why would I use the actual password? I want it to be automatically the password for the user who is logging! Anyway, I changed it as you said and it did not work! :'( See: http://screenshot.net/3rv3a43

Comment: there is no need to first two method you just use direct i given method for email and password but as i said you need to add seperate password filed on in

Comment: I did sent the project to your email. I hope you could help me. :\

Comment: let me check and reply asap

Answer (score 0):

Mariah,

The problem is your entered email and password details. You are showing the path for your email and password but instead you should enter what calls them such as.
 instead of  ""users/(self.ref.authData.uid)/email" you should provide it as ref.authData.providerData["email"]as? NSString as? String

for password you need to edit your Firebase rules so user can have access to his own password.