# Firebase. Change `username`(email) of registered user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My iOS application uses Firebase login by `username` and `password`. But I would like to give a possibility to change the `username` in settings.

The question is, does Firebase support changing a username?

**Update**

`username` means `email`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the displayName you can use this code:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = "DoesData"
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

If you want to change the email address you can use:

```
currentUser?.updateEmail(email) { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } 
    else {
        // Email updated
    }
}
```

I know you have to reauthenticate if you update a users password, but I'm not sure if you need to do that for email changes as well. 
This code can help with authentication:

```
let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)
let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

currentUser?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential) { error in
   if let error = error {
       // An error happened.
   } else {
      // User re-authenticated.
   }
}
```

You may also want to look at [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953867/changing-user-email-and-password-with-swift-and-firebase), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907324/how-to-update-both-email-and-password-with-new-firebase-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about the email and password auth method.
You can change the email (which is the username) by updating it [directly from code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address). Hope this helps!